# How to sort MySQL data by grouping priority

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

I am trying to sort the mysql data with php on grouping priority basis. I have a table called "users" contains members profile data and other table called "reviews" contains member's feedback with rating. I store rating from 0 to 5 in review_count field for reviews table.

Now I want to sort the user profile on these priority basis:

**Table "users" is like this:**

```
uid name        picture     membership_status  last_login    
--  ----------  ----------  -----------------  ------------------
1   Jhon        jhon.jpg    1                  2014-07-16 04:40:05
2   Ravi                    0                  2014-07-09 10:18:38
3   Lucy        lucy.jpg    0                  2014-07-07 11:46:53
4   Sweta                   1                  2014-07-07 11:46:53
5   Philip      philip.jpg  0                  2014-07-09 10:31:53
```

**Table reviews is like this:**

```
id     review_by     review_to   review_count
-----  -----------   ---------   ------------
1      8             1           5
2      12            2           3
3      22            5           4
```

**Now I want to sort this data on below priority basis:**

1. Premium members with last logged in
2. Reviewed members with last logged in
3. Members with photo profile with last logged in
4. Other members with last logged in

**This is my query i am using:**

```
$sel_profiles = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, 
                                    b.review_to 
                               FROM users a 
                          LEFT JOIN reviews AS b ON b.review_to = a.uid 
                           ORDER BY a.membership_status DESC, 
                                    b.review_count DESC,
                                    a.picture DESC,
                                    a.last_login DESC 
                              LIMIT 0 ,10");
```

But I am not getting correct result as i want. Please anyone can advice me how to get output as i want with grouping priority. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sel_profiles = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, 
                                b.review_to 
                           FROM users a 
                      LEFT JOIN reviews AS b ON b.review_to = a.uid 
                       ORDER BY a.last_login DESC ,
                                a.membership_status DESC                          
                          LIMIT 0 ,10");
```

Ordering by that two will itself will get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

When mysql sort by picture desc, this is an alphabetic desc order. You have to change picture by a function which return 1 when there is picture and 0 when not. Case is a good way.

```
$sel_profiles = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, b.review_to, case when a.picture is null then 1 else 0 end case DESC as isPictured FROM users a LEFT JOIN reviews AS b ON b.review_to = a.uid ORDER BY a.membership_status DESC, b.review_count DESC, isPictured DESC, a.last_login DESC LIMIT 0 ,10");
```

Try this !

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/case-statement.html

I though you have to repeat that for review_to too

Sorry for my language, I'm not fluent in English